Software to manage Outdoorcameras under Ubuntu 24.10
wich Software can do this under ubuntu 24.10?

Which cameras? Indoor or outdoor IP camera. Indoor or outdoor CCTV camera?

Outdoor cameras

https://zoneminder.com/

Thank you very much
